# Mapstruct : abstract target class and concrete type based on discriminator field

Tags: java, mapstruct

Is it possible with MapStruct to determine the concrete type of an abstract class / interface based on a discriminator property ?

Imagine a target abstract class `CarEntity` with two subclasses `SUV` and `City` and a source class `CarDto` with a discriminator field `type` with two enumeration constants `SUV` and `CITY`. How do you tell MapStruct to choose the concrete class based on the value of the discriminator field in the source class ?

Method signature would typically be :

```
public abstract CarEntity entity2Dto(CarDto dto);
```

**EDIT**

precision : `CarDto` doesn't have any subclasses.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If I understood correctly this is currently not possible. See [#131](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/131).

A way to achieve what you need would be to do something like:

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default CarEntity entity2Dto(CarDto dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (dto instance of SuvDto) {
            return fromSuv((SuvDto) dto));
        } //You need to add the rest
    }

    SuvEntity fromSuv(SuvDto dto);
}
```

Instead of doing instance of checks. You can use the discriminator field.

```
@Mapper
public interface MyMapper {

    default CarEntity entity2Dto(CarDto dto) {
        if (dto == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (Objects.equals(dto.getDiscriminator(), "suv")) {
            return fromSuv(dto));
        } //You need to add the rest
   } 

    SuvEntity fromSuv(CarDto dto);
}
```

Comment: Ok I know that sounds weird but I'm working on legacy code where CarDto doesn't have any subclasses, although CarEntity has.

Comment: Well the instance of check can be anything you want. Have a look at my updated answer.

Comment: If I do it like the second example, I get  "Ambiguous mapping methods found" because SuvEntity is extending CarEntity. Is there a workaround for that without using Qualifiers ?